# How do I get data from a QML spin box

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Having a little trouble with reading data from a QML spin box into C/C++ code. My QML code is as follows:

```
SpinBox {
    id: spinBox1
    objectName: "v_pct"
    x: 252
    y: 243
    width: 73
    height: 20
    value: 0
    stepSize: 1
    minimumValue: 0
    decimals: 0
    maximumValue: 99
}
```

I have a function that looks for the value in the spin box as follows:

```
void main_funcs::sys_set_voltage()          // sets system voltage percent of max range
{
QQuickItem* object = myDialog->rootObject();
QObject *v_spin = object->findChild<QObject*>("v_pct");     // locate voltage spinbox

QVariant vpct = v_spin->property("value").toUInt();
qDebug() << "SpinBox Data: " << vpct;
...
```

The program compiles but crashes at this point.

I've tried importing the data as a string into a QString, as a string into a QVariant, tried using the suffix .toUInt(), .toString(), .toBitArray(), .toByteArray(), but every time, the program crashes. In the case of the QString, the compiler throws an error saying that it's a type QVariant. I've even tried dropping the % suffix as well. Didn't help. Could someone shed some light? Thanks!!

Comment: `v_spin->property("text").toUInt();`; maybe you mean `->property("value")`? I don't see any "text" property in there...

Comment: Yes, sorry. I removed some irrelevant code and accidentally deleted that line from my post. Mistyped it back in...

Comment: Is `v_spin` a valid pointer? You should check it against `0` or `nullptr`

Comment: It is as far as I can tell. I've checked it. I tried using a different pointer, still no luck.

Comment: Please don't add "SOLVED" into the question title. The answer section is for, well, answers. You should accept your own answer as soon as it's possible.

Comment: Oh sorry, wasn't sure.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem - The data is a "real" qml basic type which is double precision floating point. So the solution was:

```
double vpct = v_pct->property("value").toDouble();
```

Thanks SingerOfTheFall for your input.